# Angular getting CORS No Access-Control-Allow Origin when references css file on a https server

Tags: angular

tengo un incoveniente cree un rest api en Java
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde quiero consumirlo en angular

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Headers } from '@angular/http';


import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpotifyService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log('Spotify Service Listo');
    
  }




   getAlbumHome(){

       
       return this.http.get('http://localhost:2019/ServiciosWeb13/rest/servicioAlbum/listarAlbunes').
       map(res=>{
           return res.json();
       });
       
     }
       
   /*
   getAlbumSearch(termino: string){
       return this.getQuery(`buscarByAlbum?nombre=${termino}`)
       .map(res=>res.json());
   }
  getObtenerArtista(id:String){
       return this.getQuery(`obtenerMusica?id=${id}`)
       .map(res=>res.json());
   }
   getObtenerMusica(id:String){
       return this.getQuery(`obtenerMusica?id=${id}`)
       .map(res=>res.json());
   }*/
}
```

Pero al ejecutar mi proyecto Angular me sale este error,nose como solucionarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Es por la nueva política de los navegadores. 
Necesitas configurar tu servidor web para CORS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_politica

En el encabezado(header) de tu respuesta de rest api te faltará añadir algo así:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: Me puedes decir directamente en donde puedo agregar eso? Porfavor

Comment: Habría que ver el código de tu API REST  en JAVA.

Comment: Eso yo lo configuré en el springBoot, desabilitándolo.